# Overwrite !important rule set within media-query? !unimportant?

Tags: css, media-queries

Imagine this …

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 55.5em) {
    aside[role="attend"] {
        margin:0 !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 61.5em) {
    aside[role="attend"] {
        margin:0; /* still !important but shouldn't be */
    }
}
```

Is there any way to overwrite or "remove" the `!important` declaration so it's not still applied within the higher `min-width` value?

Comment: Yeah, don't use `!important` so it does not need to be overwritten. It is way overused by people who generally are not understanding how css works. Not really an answer, hence a comment.

Comment: BTW--I did not mean by my previous comment to imply you do not know how css works. However, I did mean to imply that if possible, remove the offending `!important` by reconfiguring that selector or other css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the way the cascade works, there is no way to undo an `!important` declaration or make it "unimportant".

This is regardless of whether the rule occurs within different `@media` rules or anywhere else in a stylesheet. That means it's the same as though you didn't have the media queries there to begin with:

```css
aside[role="attend"] {
    margin:0 !important;
}

aside[role="attend"] {
    margin:0;
}
```

Which, incidentally, is what a browser actually sees if both the `min-width: 55.5em` and `min-width: 61.5em` media queries are fulfilled.

You're much better off finding a way to remove that `!important` and using a more specific selector in your first `@media` rule instead.