# Does the !important rule override media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

So for instance, if I had a media query and also some regular CSS with the !important rule on stuff, would it be affected?

For example:

```
a{
    color:#0000FF!important;
}
@media (max-width: 300px){
    a{
        color:#FF0000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it in jsFiddle?

Comment: You can find the answer yourself by just trying it yourself, don't really quite understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Media queries and `@media` rules do not affect the behavior of `!important` in any way, because [they do not have any effect on any part of the cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241531/what-are-the-rules-for-css-media-query-overlap/13611538#13611538). (By extension, this also means [you cannot use a `@media` at-rule to "remove" an `!important` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639528/overwrite-important-rule-set-within-media-query-unimportant/11640004#11640004), even if you use a more specific selector.)

When your media query is matched, the browser sees this:

```
a{
    color:#0000FF!important;
}
a{
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

And when it doesn't, it sees this:

```
a{
    color:#0000FF!important;
}
```

Both cases result in the first ruleset taking precedence, but do not prevent, for example, an `!important` declaration with a more specific selector, or an `!important` inline style, from overriding it.

Here's another example which illustrates this better:

```
a{
    color:#0000FF!important;
}
@media (max-width: 300px){
    a:link,a:visited{
        color:#FF0000!important;
    }
}
```

When the media query is matched, the browser sees this:

```
a{
    color:#0000FF!important;
}
a:link,a:visited{
    color:#FF0000!important;
}
```

This results in the second rule taking precedence because it has a more specific selector (at least for [`a` elements that match either pseudo-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10589840#10589840)). If it didn't match the media query then only the first rule would have any effect, as above.

Comment: Thanks for the visualization in the second bit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Typically if you need to use `!important`, something can be improved in your code. Here, you can see that it is overriding the media queries' change: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nx4d/1/)

If you remove `!important` form the code, the media query works as designed: [JS Fiddle working properly](http://jsfiddle.net/8nx4d/2/)

---

Recommended reading on when to use `!important`:
[When Using !important is The Right Choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Well, I have to use !important because I don't have access to the HTML or CSS, I can only add to it with another file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are using **!important** that means the css rule is not acting how you would like it to act - due to a conflict with other rules or styles (internal or external).
!important is typically - not always - a quick fix. Do professionals use it? All the time. For example - in Bootstrap 4 - the class "text-right" is marked up as follows:

```
.text-right {
        text-align: right !important;
}
```

This is great for reading - meaning you know a text will be on the right side of the screen, however in mobile view if you want to align the text differently - this will be an issue as the media query will not work. Therefore, if you can avoid using it - do. Either understand the conflict of why the new style you are applying does not work, or create a "protected" style that only works for that particular element in that section.

Take a look at jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v1tgwkq5/9/) and let me know if you have questions.

Happy coding!